# How to access contextual menu in gnome 3 dash from keyboard?

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome3

My question is simple: How do I access the contextual menu from my keyboard inside gnome 3? I've seen other answers reffering to a menu key or button but not all laptops come with that button, mine doesn't. The situation is this: I press home button, dash expands, i press `ctrl` `+` `alt` `+` `tab`, I can now browse the left bar with my favorites, then I wish I could open the context menu from here to get the "add to favorites", "open new window", etc, options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your keyboard lacks the <kbd>Menu</kbd> key, the equivalent key combination is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>.

Comment: @don_crissti The Spacebar (and Enter) trick only works with gnome-terminal and files. I looked up for Shift + F10 keybinding but didn't find it. I assume it is sort of hardcoded and can't be remapped.

Comment: Also, something happened. Now, whenever I press Enter or Spacebar (even if theres no open window of the application) GNOME opens a (inaccesible) contextual menu instead of launching the program. I have to press Esc and Shift + F10 to get an accessible contxt menu and actually launch the program.

Comment: @GilLázaro - yes, Shift+F10 is hard-coded. As to your other comment, it's either a bug in gnome-shell or I'm missing something (it randomly happens on my side too... nothing reproducible though)

Comment: @GilLázaro - dash context menu now works with both `Menu` key and `Shift+F10` in gnome 3.18; paulequilibrio - pressing the spacebar/enter key now launches the selected app, just so you know.